How can I import AudioKit Cookbook into Swift Playgrounds on iPad?
When trying to import package:
https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook
into Swift Playgrounds on iPad, I get the error 'Package does not have version tags.'
I think this is similar to https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/2643 and I was going to log a similar issue on Github, but the only available options in the bug report were for MacOS.

After logging the issue in github you will be able to change from macOS to ios.

Thanks @mahaltertin, I did that under https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/2918 and the issue was quickly closed with the comment 'The Cookbook is not a package, it is a project. It might be fun to create an iPad Playgrounds version of the Cookbook. To do so, you would need to import AudioKit, which is a package. This might be helpful: https://audiokitpro.com/drumpadplayground/' I tried downloading the .zip of the project but it's not in a form that Swift Playgrounds can open, so I guess what I was trying is not possible.

The Cookbook is not a package, it is a project. It might be fun to create an iPad Playgrounds version of the Cookbook. To do so, you would need to import AudioKit, which is a package. This might be helpful: https://audiokitpro.com/drumpadplayground/
